# (MUI) How to understand when modal is closed or opened

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

MUI `Modal` component has `onClose` callback which is fired when modal starts closing. But there is animation with delay after which modal is closed. I need to run a callback after animation is finished, but I can't find event for Modal component that serves for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```js
const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);
 ---
const handleClose = () => {
    //...some process
    setOpen(false)
};
```

Comment: It doesn't work since I need to run some processes after the modal close animation is ended. If I do it in a sync way, then my processes run before modal is closed.

To give some real-world context: there is a form inside a modal. And after the modal is closed I need to reset this form. I don't want the user to see reset junk while the form is closing with an animation delay. So I need to understand when the animation ends and only after that run my processes.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const modalIsClosed = document.getElementsByClassName("MuiDialog-root").length === 0;
  useEffect(() => {
     if (modalIsClosed === true) {
       // do something if closed
     }
   }, [modalIsClosed]);
```

Comment: `modalIsClosed` cannot get changed if it's `const`.

Comment: "The property of a const object can be changed but it cannot be changed to a reference to the new object.". It will work afaik.

Comment: It's a boolean. What property will you change?

Comment: Ok so maybe Im mistaken but it seems to work anyway. I tested it in the developer console and with my react app cause I had the same problem.

Comment: OK. It might help to show more context surrounding the code, e.g., the component you render this in. Perhaps it would make more sense then?

Comment: You are right, my component is re-rendering so const value is different hence it kinda works. But the const itself is not changing but rather it is initialized again.